# Define a static variable in matlab with the meaning like in C++

Tags: matlab

I hope that by giving an example i will be better understandable.
Assuming a binary payload with 20 bytes, which contains 5 fields.

- 1st field 4 bytes
- 2nd field 2 bytes
- 3rd field 8 bytes
- 4th field 1 byte
- 5th field 5 bytes

i would like to define in my class an offset variable to the beginning of each field and the size of it, so i could use it to decode the value of each variable.

I would like to avoid each time i create an instance of the class that those variable will need to be created and space allocated, rather then like C++, that then will be defined like `static const`... which mean it is one time defined and all other instance will use the same definition in memory.

Is this possible with Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a constant property in MATLAB by declaring the `Constant` attribute of the property:

```
classdef myClass
    properties (Constant = true)
        myProperty
    end
end
```

You will need to refer to the property qualified with the class name, for example as `myClass.myProperty`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. AT the moment they are defined as `Constant`. What i was not sure about, in order to improve preference, if there is a way of telling Matlab that they are static variables (kind of globals, but limited to a given class)

Comment: `Constant` properties are instantiated only once, when the class is first instantiated. The same value is referred to by all instances of the class - this is why they are referred to qualified with the class name. If you want access to the `Constant` property to be limited to the class itself, you can also declare it `GetAccess = private`.